# puppeteer-web: "Puppeteer is not a constructor"

Tags: google-chrome-extension, puppeteer

I'm trying to follow the [instructions here to bundle puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/tree/master/utils/browser), with the intention of including it in a chrome extension as a hacky way of scripting operations in the browser window (specifically, printing a page to PDF, which is surprisingly impossible with just the Chrome Extension API as far as I can tell).

As per the `README` in the link above, I've set up my Chrome extension as follows:

**background.html**

```
<script src="./puppeteer/utils/browser/puppeteer-web.js"></script>
<script src="background.js"></script>
```

**background.js**

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
```

Throws the error `puppeteer/utils/browser/puppeteer-web.js:10877 (anonymous function) Uncaught TypeError: Puppeteer is not a constructor`.

What am I missing here?

Chrome version: Version 69.0.3497.100

Node version: 7.4.0

Comment: Finally someone made a question about puppeteer web. :D  Can you share a bit of your code?

Comment: I tested out puppeteer-web, so far it worked absolutely fine for me. Can you tell me your browser version, node version etc so we can figure out what's wrong?

Comment: @Md.AbuTaher I've updated the details!

Comment: What I cannot understand is, the error log says `Puppeteer`, not `puppeteer`. Are you sure the error happens if you just require the library?

Comment: Yeah, it's erroring on this line: `module.exports = new Puppeteer(__dirname, preferredRevision, isPuppeteerCore);` (in `puppeteer-web.js`). Is there another way to `require` it besides how I have it above?

Comment: Provided working solution as answer, added an issue https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/3455 just in case. Peace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome extensions does not allow `unsafe-eval`, that is reason why puppeteer is not working on chrome extension. Set the following on `manifest.json`.

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
```

Tested with following code,

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function getTitle() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.connect({
    browserWSEndpoint: 'ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/browser/9f0a2240-2cb7-4efa-ac3c-8ef883d36d12',
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('http://example.com');
  const title = await page.title();
  await page.close();
  await browser.disconnect();
  return title;
}

getTitle().then(console.log);
```

## Result:

[image]

## How did I find it:

The code is running perfectly if I run it directly or put it on a page, but wasn't working from chrome extension only.

The `asyncawait` check here helped me find the culprit.

```
let asyncawait = true;
try {
  new Function('async function test(){await 1}');
} catch (error) {
  asyncawait = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! I assume you got the `browserWSEndpoint` by running chrome.exe with special command line flags -- do you happen to know if there's a way to programmatically get that endpoint for another tab in your own browser (if puppeteer is running in the extension's background window)?