# How to run Puppeteer code in any web browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to do some web scraping with Puppeteer and I need to retrieve the value into a Website I'm building.

I have tried to load the Puppeteer file in the html file as if it was a JavaScript file but I keep getting an error. However, if I run it in a cmd window it works well.

Scraper.js:

```
getPrice();
function getPrice() {
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    void (async () => {
        try {
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
            const page = await browser.newPage()              
            await page.goto('http://example.com') 
            await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 938 })        
            await page.waitForSelector('.m-hotel-info > .l-container > .l-header-section > .l-m-col-2 > .m-button')
            await page.click('.m-hotel-info > .l-container > .l-header-section > .l-m-col-2 > .m-button')
            await page.waitForSelector('.modal-content')
            await page.click('.tile-hsearch-hws > .m-search-tabs > #edit-search-panel > .l-em-reset > .m-field-wrap > .l-xs-col-4 > .analytics-click')
            await page.waitForNavigation();
            await page.waitForSelector('.tile-search-filter > .l-display-none')
            const innerText = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('.tile-search-filter > .l-display-none').innerText);
            console.log(innerText)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }

    })()
}
```

index.html:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <script src="../js/scraper.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The expected result should be this one in the console of Chrome:

[image]

But I'm getting this error instead:

[image]
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: puppeteer is a headless browser, you can't load it inside a web browser. For other packages that can be run in the browser take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined

Comment: You can translate Puppeteer commands to respective browser API but some likely won't work. `waitForNavigation` - how do you expect it to work? You navigate to another page. There will be another page that will be unaware of this script. The reason why Node packages like Puppeteer exist is that some things cannot be achieved with a browser alone.

Comment: Thanks to you both! 
I have tried Browserify and I keep getting this error: https://i.imgur.com/LfWOlyv.png I guess puppeteer doesn't work with Browserify?

I use waitForNavigation because I need to get a value that appears after clicking a button, so I have to use it or otherwise I wouldn't be able to get that value because it doesn't wait until the site is completely loaded by itself.

All I need is to send the value of the constant innerText to JavaScript, so then I will be able to use it in the website I'm building with HTML, CSS and JS but I have no idea about how to achieve that.

Comment: Those errors should be given as [text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**EDIT: Since puppeteer removed support for puppeteer-web, I moved it out of the repo and tried to patch it a bit.**

It does work with browser. The package is called [puppeteer-web](https://github.com/entrptaher/puppeteer-web), specifically made for such cases.

But the main point is, there must be some instance of chrome running on some server. Only then you can connect to it.

You can use it later on in your web page to drive another browser instance through its WS Endpoint:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/puppeteer-web">
</script>

<script>
  const browser = await puppeteer.connect({
    browserWSEndpoint: `ws://0.0.0.0:8080`, // <-- connect to a server running somewhere
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true
  });

  const pagesCount = (await browser.pages()).length;
  const browserWSEndpoint = await browser.wsEndpoint();
  console.log({ browserWSEndpoint, pagesCount });
</script>
```

I had some fun with puppeteer and webpack,

- [playground-react-puppeteer](https://github.com/entrptaher/playground-react-puppeteer)
- [playground-electron-react-puppeteer-example](https://github.com/entrptaher/playground-electron-react-puppeteer-example)

See these answers for full understanding of creating the server and more,

- [Official link to puppeteer-web](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/tree/master/utils/browser)
- [Puppeteer with docker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51750943/6161265)
- [Puppeteer with chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53024164/6161265)
- [Puppeteer with local wsEndpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51732895/6161265)

Comment: Well, that's kinda hard in my opinion... I'm trying out another alternative that is called Goutte, it seems to fit better for my needs and it's easier when it comes to show the results in a web browser since it uses PHP and it doesn't require an external command. Anyway, I will save your answer in case I need it in the future. Thank you so much!!

Comment: You are welcome. However, since your question was regarding puppeteer, and not about scraping in general, I am sure the answer fits your question perfectly :D .

Comment: Official links 404'd

Comment: Here's the old [link](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/tree/6522e4f524bdbc1f1b9d040772acf862517ed507/utils/browser) from a past commit. It looks like they removed it in this [pull request](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/pull/5750)

Comment: Looks like I need to find an alternative for it soon and update the answers. :D Gimme a bit of time, I'll check after weekends.

Comment: This is very interesting. Thanks for sharing. Is it possible to extract the part of puppeteer that creates a PNG/JPG/PDF screenshot of HTML and create a separate library that could run in the browser to allow for browser-based screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

Puppeteer runs on the server in Node.js. For the common case, rather than using puppeteer-web to allow the client to write Puppeteer code to control the browser, it's better to create an HTTP or websocket API that lets clients indirectly trigger Puppeteer code.

Reasons to prefer a REST API over puppeteer-connect:

- better support for arbitrary client codebases--clients that aren't written in JS (desktop, command line and mobile apps, for example) can use the API just as easily as the browser can
- no dependency on puppeteer-connect
- lower client-side complexity; for many use cases JS won't be required at all if HTML forms suffice
- better control of client behavior--running a browser on the server is a heavy load and has powerful capabilities that are easy to exploit
- easier to integrate with other backend code and resources like the file system
- provides seamless integration with an existing API as just another set of routes
- hiding Puppeteer as an implementation detail lets you switch to, say, Playwright in the future without the client code being affected.

Similarly, rather than exposing a mock `fs` object to read and write files on the server, we expose REST API endpoints to accomplish these tasks. This is a useful layer of abstraction.

Since there are many use cases for Puppeteer in the context of an API (usually Express), it's hard to offer a general example, but here are a few case studies you can use as starting points:

- [Puppeteer unable to run on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52225461/puppeteer-unable-to-run-on-heroku/67596057#67596057)
- [Puppeteer doesn't close browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53939503/puppeteer-doesnt-close-browser/67910262#67910262)
- [Parallelism of Puppeteer with Express Router Node JS. How to pass page between routes while maintaining concurrency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66935883/parallelism-of-puppeteer-with-express-router-node-js-how-to-pass-page-between-r/66946923#66946923)

Answer (score 0):

Instead, use Puppeteer in the backend and make an API to interface your frontend with it if your main goal is to web scrape and get the data in the frontend.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33328477)