# Puppeeteer issue in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, puppeteer

Trying to install puppeteer in windows which is installed but app is not coming with the below errors.

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '**http**' in
>   'C:\xxx\my-pup\node_modules\puppeteer\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve '**https**' in
>   'C:\xxx\my-pup\node_modules\puppeteer\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve '**os**' in 'C:\xxx\my-pup\node_modules\puppeteer\lib'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve '**path**' in
>   'C:\xxx\my-pup\node_modules\puppeteer\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/JSHandle.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve '**path**' in 'C:\xxx\my-pup\node_modules\puppeteer\lib'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/WebSocketTransport.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve '**ws**' in
>   'C:\xxx\my-pup\node_modules\puppeteer\lib'

Even tried to install http,https,os,path,ws but still the same .

Tried installing different versions of puppeteer and other dependencies from npm page.

Cleaned the cache 
npm cache clean --force

Installed latest node, npm versions and latest angular-cli

Comment: Unfortunately Puppeteer will not work normally with Angular, React, Vue etc. because they are browser based and puppeteer requires nodeJS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Puppeteer code in any web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54647694/how-to-run-puppeteer-code-in-any-web-browser)

Comment: any other alternative to puppeteer that can be used in Angular ?

Comment: That would be like asking if you can run a browser inside a browser. You need a server somewhere, there is no other way, as far as I know.

Comment: Interesting since we have no other way. Server/client setup will complicate smooth installation.

Comment: How do you start the Angular/Puppeteer application? All the examples I see start the application with `ng test app` but I don't want to test it, I want to use it to generate PDFs/images at server side