# How to exclude by webpack.config.js, or fix this problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm using react create app to make a website,and I almost complete my code,
but after I import 'puppeteer',there are many error come out.
e.g.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/yauzl/index.js 13:16-43
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\User\Documents\VSCode\lubnx\node_modules\yauzl'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
        - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
 @ ./node_modules/extract-zip/index.js 19:14-30
 @ ./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserFetcher.js 75:38-60
 @ ./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/Puppeteer.js 31:28-58
 @ ./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/initialize-node.js 29:23-53
 @ ./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node.js 22:29-60
 @ ./node_modules/puppeteer/cjs-entry.js 28:24-59
 @ ./src/bsc.js 3:18-38
 @ ./src/App.js 9:0-24
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 13:35-38

90 errors have detailed information that is not shown.
Use 'stats.errorDetails: true' resp. '--stats-error-details' to show it.

webpack 5.65.0 compiled with 90 errors and 58 warnings in 2608 ms
```

There are so many errors,and I have no idea.
I have crawled some website but still confused,I try to make a webpack.config.js,but it seems don't work.

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: [
      './index.js'
    ],
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname,"public"),
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules:[
            {
                test: /\.yauzl$/,
                exclude: /\.js$/,
            }
        ]
    }
  };
```

here is my puppeteer code

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const dappeteer = require('@chainsafe/dappeteer');

const seed = 'quote violin crane pride emotion cart pyramid grunt custom release work sauce';
const mining = 'https://www.binaryx.pro/#/game/work?workType=partTime&work=2';

const bsc = async()=> {
  const browser = await dappeteer.launch(puppeteer, { metamaskVersion: 'v10.1.1' });

  const metamask = await dappeteer.setupMetamask(browser, {
    seed: seed,
    password: 'pass1234',
});

  await metamask.addNetwork({
    networkName: 'BSC',
    rpc: 'https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org/',
    chainId: 56,
    symbol: 'BNB',
    explorer: 'https://bscscan.com/',
  });

  await metamask.switchNetwork('BSC');

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(mining, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
  await metamask.approve();
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 7000));
  return (
    await page.evaluate(async() => {
      const mn = document.querySelector('#app > section > main > div > div.work-page > div.job-record > div.flex-between.record-title--wrap > span > div');
      const res = mn.innerText;
      return res;
    })
  )
}
bsc();
```

export default bsc;

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here that you need to bundle something like Puppeteer with webpack...? Can you explain, in your own words, what you're using Puppeteer for?

Comment: I'm trying to crawl an other website,so I need puppeteer,when I import 'puppeteer' in my code,and run npm start,I'll get these error.

Comment: Puppeteer is *not* designed to run in a browser. Why are you trying to use it as such?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run Puppeteer code in any web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54647694/how-to-run-puppeteer-code-in-any-web-browser)

Answer (score 0):

As Webpack suggests, you can include the `stream` polyfill by adding a fallback (`resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }`):

```js
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: [
      './index.js'
    ],
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname,"public"),
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        fallback: {
            "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify");
        }
    }
    module: {
        rules:[
            {
                test: /\.yauzl$/,
                exclude: /\.js$/,
            }
        ]
    }
  };
```

And install `stream-browserify`:

```sh
npm i stream-browserify
```

You can read more about `resolve.fallback` [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvefallback).

---

Comment: I have done just like yours,but the error still happen.

const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: [
      './index.js'
    ],
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname,"public"),
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        fallback: {
          "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
          "fs": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules:[
            {
                test: /\.yauzl$/,
                exclude: /\.js$/,
            }
        ]
    }
};

Comment: @huihui That's interesting...Could I take a look at your full code (or repository?)

Comment: Sure! https://github.com/hp41299889/lubnx

Comment: I don't...seem to see a `webpack.config.js`

Comment: oh, maybe I forgot push the latest version, but I did just like I posted.

Comment: I can't help you if the file isn't there :/