# How to fetch asynchronously loading website (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm trying to fetch an URL from another page (need to check if some classes there are available).

Unfortunately, when I get a response from the server and read HTML I don't get full content - some parts are loaded by React after my fetch finishes. Is there any way to get the content without opening this page in another tab?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54647694/how-to-run-puppeteer-code-in-any-web-browser maybe - looks difficult. A better approach would be to do the scraping on your server, which can fully emulate the page loading

Comment: Don't load the "page", just load the data from the same API as their react application.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -2):

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com');
  // Wait for some element to be available
  await page.waitForSelector('.your-class-selector');
  const content = await page.content();
  console.log(content);
  await browser.close();
})();
```