# the package (puppeteer) ReferenceError: process is not defined vue 3

Tags: vuejs3, puppeteer

puppeteerrc.json in root file

```
{
    "experiments": {
      "macArmChromiumEnabled": true
    }
  }
```

webscrap.js

```
// Import puppeteer
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

let puppeteerweb =(async () => {
  // Launch the browser
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

  // Create a page
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // Go to your site
  await page.goto('YOUR_SITE');

  // Query for an element handle.
  const element = await page.waitForSelector('div > .class-name');

  // Do something with element...
  await element.click(); // Just an example.

  // Dispose of handle
  await element.dispose();

  // Close browser.
  await browser.close();
})();

export default puppeteerweb;
```

Webscrap.vue

```
<script setup>
import puppeteerweb from "../../webscrap";
</script>

<template></template>
```

here i ateying to website warpper paricluar div using
the package (puppeteer).but igot a error
ReferenceError: process is not defined
how to solve this?

Comment: Puppeteer runs on Node, not the browser. Just calling it the variable name `puppeteerweb` doesn't change that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run Puppeteer code in any web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54647694/how-to-run-puppeteer-code-in-any-web-browser)