# puppeteer-core problem! Can't resolve 'fs', 'http'

Tags: reactjs, web-scraping, webpack, puppeteer

I am making web scraping site,
and I want get Tags in URL , but they are dynamic sources.

so I can't touch only Cheerio.
people recommended Puppeteer. and my problem was starting

first. I could see Module not found:

```
Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/Users/Documents/myMac/Study/bookMarks/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node'
```

and also they couldn't find out os, path .....

so I add (I use yarn) webpack and cli

second. I set the webpack.config.js for fallback

```
    resolve:{
        fallback:{
            "fs":false,
            "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser"),
            "path": require.resolve("path-browserify"),
            "https": require.resolve("https-browserify"),
            "stream": false,
            "zlib": false ,
            "crypto": false,
            "constants": false,
        }
}
```

because the Err-Message said

```
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
        - install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "https": false }
```

but the err messages still there when I yarn start

Third. I thought if the config didn't set .
so I did ' `$ webpack --config webpack.config.js`'
I couldn't see the err

but still when I did yarn start, problem are there

4th. I add fs, os, http..... (in the err's module name) using yarn
I can see the dependencies

`"os": "^0.1.2",      "path": "^0.12.7",`

and added

```
  "browser": {
    "crypto": false,
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
    "os": false,
    "net": false,
    "stream": false,
    "tls": false
  }
```

setting in package.json

but,,
.
.
.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/FirefoxLauncher.js 43:29-42
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/Documents/myMac/Study/bookMarks/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node'

ERROR in ./node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ProductLauncher.js 65:13-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/Documents/myMac/Study/bookMarks/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node'

webpack compiled with 41 errors
```

I am having 41 errors

5th . I removed folder the **node_modules** and **yarn.lock**
and did
`$ yarn cache clean  $ yarn install`

it doesn't work

also I removed **puppeteer-core** and re-add

and i have 41 errors still

do you have another way
or
can I alternate puppeteer?

at last
this is js module using puppeteer

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');
const DomParser = require('dom-parser');

async function getTagList(url) {
  const tagListText = new Array();
  try{
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);

    const html = await page.content();
    const parser = new DomParser();
    const dom = parser.parseFromString(html);
    const tagList = dom.getElementsByClassName('tag_area')[0].getElementsByTagName('a');
    tagListText = Array.from(tagList).map(tag => tag.textContent);

    await browser.close();
  }catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
  }

  return tagListText;
}

module.exports = { getTagList };
```

and I am using chatGPT. he recommended setting in webpack.config.js
Specially fallback -> fallbacks
and it can't terminal said fallbacks isn't option

I use webpack5

Comment: I tried "webdriverio" for alternative option And it made same result

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run Puppeteer code in any web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54647694/how-to-run-puppeteer-code-in-any-web-browser)

Comment: puppeteer is node only. It doesn't run in a browser.

Comment: this day, I don't use node server(and any server) I thing it make problems...

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason.

I don't use a node server.
if I want use puppeteer, I need to use node server